# Is this interpretation correct for this probability question?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Seven chits are numbered $1$ to $7$. Three are drawn one by one with replacements. The probability that the least number on any selected chit is $5$, is

My teacher says that the favourable outcomes are $5, 6, 7$, so the probability is $\left( \frac 3 7 \right)^3$.

But I think that this also includes cases like $(6, 6, 7)$. So I'm getting the probability of $\frac{3^3-2^3}{7^3}$, after excluding the cases of only $6$'s and $7$'s.

Which of these is the correct interpretation of the question? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you excluding cases which have only $6$ or $7$?

Comment: @Math Lover If the least number is $5$, then a $5$ must be present.

Comment: @DanielMathias that is not how I would interpret. The least number on any selected chit is $5$ means it can be either $5, 6$ or $7$.

Comment: I agree that there is ambiguity. The solution depends upon whether "The probability that the least number on any selected chit is 5" means the least value of the three draws is exactly $5$ or if we are looking for the probability that each selection has a value that is at least $5$.

Comment: @Math Lover $x=5$ does not mean $x\ge 5$ There is absolutely no ambiguity here.

Comment: @DanielMathias the last comment was not from me. Also based on what it says, it is $x \geq 5$. Where are you reading $x = 5$?

Comment: @Math Lover "probability that the number is $5$" $P(x=5)$ The word "least" is used to indicate the minimum value in the set of numbers drawn. If the intention was $\ge 5$, the text would read "... is at least $5$"

Comment: @DanielMathias I do not agree with your interpretation. The least number on any selected chit is $5$ means if you take any chit, it could be $5, 6$ or $7$. Anyway I will leave it at that.

Comment: This is just an issue where the problem itself needs to be clarified, since there are two reasonable interpretations.  I would have assumed that the correct interpretation is the most interesting one, for which we require at least one "5," so I would also have given $(3/7)^3-(2/7)^3$ as my answer. I may have written "assuming we need at least one 5" on my paper to emphasize which scenario I was using.

Answer (score 1):

The event was that the least number that shows on any of the three draws is $5$.

The event was **not** that $5$ is the smallest number showing on the three draws.

There is no requirement that $5$ shows on any draw; only that nothing less than that ever shows.

Comment: If there is no $5$, then $5$ cannot be the least number shown.

Comment: I cannot tell the difference between the cases of your first two sentences.